# Why am I getting Error CS0016 Could not write to output file in ASP.NET Core 7.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, visual-studio-2022

I'm getting this error:

> **Error   CS0016**    Could not write to output file 'C:\Users\jp2code\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\Core\Mvc1\Mvc1\obj\Debug\net7.0\generated\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Views_Shared__ValidationScriptsPartial_cshtml.g.cs' -- 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\jp2code\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\Core\Mvc1\Mvc1\obj\Debug\net7.0\generated\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Views_Shared__ValidationScriptsPartial_cshtml.g.cs'.'    Mvc1    C:\Users\jp2code\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\Core\Mvc1\Mvc1\CSS

The file Visual Studio is looking for is here:

`C:\Users\jp2code\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\Core\Mvc1\Mvc1\obj\Debug\net7.0\generated\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Views_Shared__ValidationScriptsPartial_cshtml.g.cs`

It is not in that location, so Visual Studio is correct.

[image: screenshot of missing file]

My understanding is that a generated file like `Views_Shared__ValidationScriptsPartial_cshtml.g.cs` is supposed to come from a file in the path "Views > Shared > _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml", which ***DOES*** exist:

[image: screenshot of existing file]

### How do I fix this error?

Comment: Maybe try deleting the hidden .vs folder that is at your solutions root and then rebuilding?

Comment: @TimothyG. I crossed my fingers, but that didn't fix the issue. Now I'm sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was from the file **_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml** in the project. The contents of this file was just 2 script files:

```html
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I excluded that one file from the project, and the project rebuilds fine.

I don't understand that error. Why would Visual Studio add that file, and then the compiler complain about not being able to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever got this solved, but for you and anyone else who comes across this issue, I had a similar error occur when I was trying to compile Visual studio 2022 projects. I finally figured out that my Windows installation was not configured to support long paths, and therefore, not all the files that needed to be generated were generated.

The solution was to simply modify a registry enabling long paths.

The following link provides the specifics:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry

Comment: I got my issue resolved, but thanks for chiming in. It can be quiet in here sometimes when you ask a question.